# How to change markerTintColor of specific annotationView in swift4

Tags: swift, annotations, swift4, plist, swift5

I created a property list for location details, title, subtitle ,type and coordinates. What I am trying to do is change the annotationView color according to the type of the location.In my code the compiler move directly to else statement. ***Could someone explain how can I solve this?***

```
       func readRecordFromPlist(){
        //read record from plist code
    }

       func mapView(_ MapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> 
        MKAnnotationView? {

      let obj = userNSObj()
      if obj.type == "Type1" {
      let view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
      view.markerTintColor = .blue
      return view
      }else{
      let view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
      view.markerTintColor = .purple
      return view
    }
   }
```

Comment: show your `userNSObj` code

Comment: I think my mistake is trying to read the obj.type from userNSObj which just has variables will what I did is appending the values of plist to empty array. Now I can assume that I need to read the value from the array, but how?